# iOS - Localize a static constants

Tags: ios, swift, localization, constants

I have this static let in a constants class:

```
struct Constants {
   struct AlertsIdentifiers {
     static let SERVER_RESTART_MESSAGE = """
     The camera will restart now.
     Please reconnect after two minutes.
    """
   }
  }
```

I am starting to localize the app.
How can i localize that kind of string?

In my localize.string file is use this code:

```
"The camera will restart now.Please reconnect after two minutes." = "The camera will restart now.Please reconnect after two minutes.";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
static let SERVER_RESTART_MESSAGE =  NSLocalizedString("camReConnect", comment: "")
```

---

```
"camReConnect" = "The camera will restart now. \n Please reconnect after two minutes.";
```

It's a good practice to shorten the length of the key at the same time of making it readable

Comment: It's a good idea yet i need to show it in alert as in the original convention above - that is  2 lines , one above the other. 
make cense ?

Comment: `"now.\nPlease"`

Comment: The \n was missing!
 i should have seen that
thanks!

Comment: Btw - have same problem with a larger text:
      static let PENDING_DEVICE_SAVED_MESSAGE = """
        To complete onboarding:
        1. Tap Save and disconnect to disconnect from the camera.
        2. Connect to the internet.
        3. Log in to Cloud.
        4. Open the Pending Cameras screen.
        """
tried  the same way yet nothing , any ideas?

Comment: every place you need a new line insert \n in your last string you may need 3 \n

Comment: Tried that:
"To complete onboarding:\n1. Tap Save and disconnect to disconnect from the camera.\n2. Connect to the internet.\n3. Log in to FLIR Cloud.\n4. Open the Pending Cameras screen." = "To complete onboarding:\n1. Tap Save and disconnect to disconnect from the camera.\n2. Connect to the internet.\n3. Log in to Cloud.\n4. Open the Pending Cameras screen.";
no success ...
can you see the mistake?

Comment: "To complete onboarding: \n 1. Tap Save and disconnect to disconnect from the camera. \n2 . Connect to the internet. \n3 . Log in to Cloud. \n4 . Open the Pending Cameras screen." = "To complete onboarding:\n1. Tap Save and disconnect to disconnect from the camera.\n2. Connect to the internet.\n3. Log in to Cloud.\n4. Open the Pending Cameras screen.";
not working for some reason

Comment: Do this `"camReConnect" = "To complete onboarding:\n1. Tap Save and disconnect to disconnect from the camera.\n2. Connect to the internet.\n3. Log in to Cloud.\n4. Open the Pending Cameras screen."`

Comment: the \n should be in value not in key

Comment: but i want the same convention in the value also

Comment: them make the key as you want  but without \n

Comment: but the key is this:
       static let PENDING_DEVICE_SAVED_MESSAGE = """
        To complete onboarding:
        1. Tap Save and disconnect to disconnect from the camera.
        2. Connect to the internet.
        3. Log in to Cloud.
        4. Open the Pending Cameras screen.
        """

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185733/discussion-between-ironroei-and-sh-khan).

Comment: "It's a good practice to shorten the length of the key at the same time of making it readable." ... If you're going to talk about best practices, you really need to provide some context (e.g. perhaps a slightly less cryptic key, include a comment string, etc.). A translator doesn't have a prayer of knowing what to do if you just provide `camReConnect`.

Comment: @Rob the translator will translate the values not keys , and off course they should be written in a proper grammer to be translated correctly , BTW i mean it short from the perspective of the developer , Do you think it's right to leave the key as the op did ?

Comment: First, my main point is that any discussion of "best practice" is incomplete without a reminder that one should not leave the comment field empty. Second, if you're going to push me on the `camReConnect` key, no I don't personally think that's a particularly good key. One should be able to look at the code and immediately know what that line of code is going to do without digging through localization file(s). Shorten it a bit if you want, but the gist of the message should be obvious. And while not the case here, I think this is doubly important if you're using `localizedStringWithFormat`.

Comment: @Rob i agree that clarification goes hand in hand with long meaningful key , but my point is not to make it like what the op is doing , the matter of shortcut key differs from one developer to the other and for sure that will leave a possibility of 30% for digging

Answer (score 0):

You can define your strings in localizable file and use it across the project,

In `Localizable.strings` file,

```
"SERVER_RESTART_MESSAGE" = "The camera will restart now.Please reconnect after two minutes.";
```

Then in `Constants` use the string like,

```
struct Constants {
   struct AlertsIdentifiers {
     static let SERVER_RESTART_MESSAGE = NSLocalizedString("SERVER_RESTART_MESSAGE", comment: "")
   }
}
```